# Is there a way to use Shopify MetaFields to tag customers with data?

Tags: metadata, shopify, liquid

I've been trying to find a way to store a piece of data relative to a customer in my store. Ideally I was hoping to be able to create a Metafield that would store a single numerical value and be retrievable by the customer's id or email.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be really appreciated. Ideally I'd like to be able to handle everything in the liquid layer by editing the html and css of the store directly. A custom app with API integration is another option but less desirable as it doesn't seem necessary and would appear to be a lot more work.

EDIT: Tried piggybacking the order (thinking orders are unique to users) but it doesn't appear that the order object is created until the checkout is complete so that isn't really useful since I want to be able to attribute the user to a session click that led them to the store.

Thanks, 
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use an App. First, off, that is the only way for you to alter any objects in Shopify. Secondly, you can easily store simple things like counter values on the Customer resource using metafields. Third, anything you do with metafields on the Customer would be easily visible to the customer, since you can expose those metafields using Liquid. Fourth, if you choose to use JS you must use the App Proxy pattern. Shopify will then send your JS XHR payload to your App endpoint in a secure fashion.

So your needs and how to do are not new, they are old skool in Shopify terms and very straightforward to implement.

Comment: Great details @David thanks! I'll give these options a try and get back to you!